# Get the Value data of a Value name within a registry KEY

Tags: javascript, vbscript, dom-events

I have the Javascript below. I want to get the data of a value name in a particular registry key. For example, if the key is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\VideoLAN\\VLC` and the value name is `InstallDir`, how can I get the data of `InstallDir` (which is a path, i.e. `D:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC`). How can I get this path in JavaScript or VBScript?

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  MyObject = new ActiveXObject( "WScript.Shell" )
  function Goto()
  {
    var bat= MyObject.RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\InstallDir");
    MyObject.Run("bat/GoToLine2.bat 10 /examples/helloWorld/helloWorld.txt") ;
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="Goto()">Run BatFile</button>
</body>
</html>
```

As you might see, I want the file path of `InstallDir` to be saved in a variable (bat) to run a batch file (`GoToLine2.bat`) which is located in the value data of `InstallDir` (i.e. `D:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC`). Can you please tell me how can I get this path so that I don't have to use

```
MyObject.Run("D:/Program Files/VideoLAN/VLC/GoToLine2.bat 10 /examples/helloWorld/helloWorld.txt");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MyObject.Run(bat + "\\GoToLine2.bat 10 /examples/helloWorld/helloWorld.txt");
```

Ok, I think I get what's wrong. The path has space, so you need to enclose it with quotes, i.e.:

```
MyObject.Run("\"" + bat + "\\GoToLine2.bat\" 10 /examples/helloWorld/helloWorld.txt");
```

Comment: How exactly not work? If you're not more concrete then how to help?

Comment: my apologies..i am not sure...i replaced your code..and opened the html file in internet explorer and clicked the button and it didn't run...but when i used the path "D:/Program Files/VideoLAN/VLC/GoToLine2.bat" it worked.Has it got to do something with value not being stored as string???im not sure...bare with my naiveness :(

Answer (score 0):

In some languages you can use variable interpolation/substitution to put the content of a variable into a string literal:

```
perl -e 'my $v = "c"; my $s = "${v}x"; print $s, "\n";'
cx
```

Neither VBScript not J(ava)script have this feature:

```
% v = "c" // given variable v containing "c"
c
% s = "vx" // j(ava)script does not interpolate
vx
% s = v + "x" // so use concatenation
cx
```

Another option is to use Replace instead of concatenation:

```
>> v = "c"
>> s = Replace("$vx", "$v", v)
>> WScript.Echo s
>>
cx
```